# How to manage data(HTML) from callback function with jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, post

I'm a not a good developper in Java EE and Ajax and I have a problem when I get information from A Servlet:

This is my JS file:

```
            $password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
            $name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var $hash="";
            if ( $password  != '') {
                $hash = hex_md5($password);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'identification',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{pass:$hash,name:$name},
                dataType: 'html',
                timeout: 1000,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);

                    if(data=='no'){
                                    $("#messages").html("Authentication prob ");
                                  }
                    else if(data=='db'){
                        $("#messages").html(" DataBase prob ");
                      }
                    else
                    {
                        $("body").html(data);
                        //or i want to redirect to new page
                    //window.location ="/BookListServlet?nom="+$nom;
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is my Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String name= request.getParameter("name");
    String pass=request.getParameter("pass");

    if (name.length()==0)
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("no");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }

    else if (name.equals("admin")&&pass.equals("0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661"))
    {
        if(bookiml.get_connection()!=null)//db is ok
        {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/BookListServlet").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("db");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }

    }

    else 
    {
     response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("no");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**I have a big problem: redirecting a page and getting HTML content from a Servlet**

I need to forward the request send for identification to this `booklistservlet` and then get a page from the Servlet.

Why is this code not working?

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Thanks for answer,i mean $("#messages").html(...) and $("body").html(data); is not working but alert(data) is working

Comment: additionally, javascript cryptography is not appreciated. http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: some thing with no hash password

Answer (score 0):

ok, the `data` is not actually the direct value you returns from the server, instead it is an html page. (Response of the server). Therefore you have to manipulate the `data`, with JQuery you can simply do it

```
var password = $('#pass').val();
var name = $('#name').val();
var hash="";
if ( password  != '') {
    hash = hex_md5(password);
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'identification',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        pass:hash,
        name:name
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);

        if($(data).find('body').text()=='no'){
            $("#messages").html("Authentication prob ");
        }
        else if($(data).find('body').text()=='db'){
            $("#messages").html(" DataBase prob ");
        }
        else
        {
            $("body").html($(data).find('body').text());
        //or i want to redirect to new page
        //window.location ="/BookListServlet?nom="+$nom;
        }
    }
});
```

P.S

For logging purpose i'd prefer to use `console.log();` instead of alert boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but it is not working , my page become a blank page

Comment: have you tried `console.log($(data))`? what was the output? in chrome by hitting f12 you will get the console window.

Comment: @Splinky of course, explain me `response.setContentType("text/html");` then. You can actually see the values which you returned in the console. look at my complete corrected code

Comment: some thing bro ,i can't find any error, and the still blank when i click the botton,(i tried with datatype XML and i can test all thing but i can't parse html page (returned from server) because it accept only XML ,so should fix these code soon :)